# Have C# code run in a different timezone to local time

Tags: c#, xml

I have a windows service which consumes XML data. The XSD datetime values contain offsets from a given timezone, so on deserialization these are converted to local time. The windows service then commits this data to a DB.

My problem is that the users of the database don't care about timezone at all. They want to see date values in the local time of whereever the date came from.

I was thinking that I could have the windows service code run in a different timezone to local server time in order that the deserializer would not apply the conversion to local time.

1. Is this a good idea?
2. Can I even do this? All of what I have read so far says that no, I can't because .net doesn't just assumes the timezone of the server it's running on.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't convert to the data-consumers timezone on read?

Comment: Are you able to modify the source code to this windows service?

Comment: @rowlandshaw That is the problem. I am converting to the data-consumers time zone. However this is exactly what they don't want to see. They want to see the datetime in the local time of the place where the data originated

Comment: @hometoast yes I am able to do this.

Comment: You said yourself, the XML contains the datetime *with* timezone info.

Comment: I don't want to do a manual conversion of the date to the desired timezone in code. I would rather do it if possible by setting the windows service to run in the desired timezone

Comment: Cue Skeet with [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) link in 3...2...1...

Comment: What I meant to add is while I can change the windows service, I would rather not. My ideal solution would be to put something in the app config which would mean the whole service runs in EST.

Comment: hometoast that made me laugh... Isnt that a bot looking c# time related questions that adds the link... Then a link to C# DateTimeOffset :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to do a manual conversion of the date to the desired
>   timezone in code. I would rather do it if possible by setting the
>   windows service to run in the desired timezone – hugh 12 secs ago

The answer to this question then, is No. You can't set a service to run in a different time zone than the computer.  Also that would make this question not programming-related.

Comment: Thanks - I will have to do the conversion by hand then.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to store the dates in the database as UTC date times.

You can retrieve the UTC date using DateTime.UtcNow.

And when you want to use the local time you would use DateTime.Now

This MSDN page explains the DateTime structure in more depth
[DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: quick add links to NodaTime and MSDN DateTimeOffset, then you win